# how to set setContentView?

Tags: java, android, xml, actionbarsherlock, imageswitcher

i creating a project using actionbarsherlock "menuviewpager" I want to put the class from my project in it. but i got several error. I want to insert imageswitcher into the fragment in the *manueviewpager's* project.

here are the code that i already copy and past into the projects.There are four error that i got:-

- setContentView
- findViewById
- Fragment1.this;
- .padding_medium);

**Fragment1.java**

```
package com.androidbegin.menuviewpagertutorial;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;




public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tandaamaran);//<---------here are the error "setContentView"

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);//<---------here are the error "findViewById"
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
      {
        private int[] mImages = new int[] 
        {

            R.drawable.pic01,
            R.drawable.pic02,
            R.drawable.pic03,
            R.drawable.pic04,
            R.drawable.pic05,
            R.drawable.pic06,
            R.drawable.pic07,
            R.drawable.pic08,
            R.drawable.pic09,
            R.drawable.pic10,
            R.drawable.pic11,
            R.drawable.pic12,
            R.drawable.pic13,
            R.drawable.pic14,
            R.drawable.pic15,
            R.drawable.pic16,
            R.drawable.pic17,
            R.drawable.pic18,
            R.drawable.pic19,
            R.drawable.pic20,
            R.drawable.pic21,
            R.drawable.pic22,
            R.drawable.pic23,
            R.drawable.pic24,
            R.drawable.pic25,
            R.drawable.pic26,
            R.drawable.pic27,
            R.drawable.pic28,
            R.drawable.pic29,
            R.drawable.pic30,
            R.drawable.pic31,
            R.drawable.pic32,
            R.drawable.pic33,
            R.drawable.pic34,
            R.drawable.pic35,
            R.drawable.pic36,
            R.drawable.pic37,
            R.drawable.pic38,
            R.drawable.pic39,
            R.drawable.pic40,
            R.drawable.pic41,
            R.drawable.pic42,
            R.drawable.pic43,
            R.drawable.pic44,
            R.drawable.pic45,
            R.drawable.pic46,
            R.drawable.pic47,
            R.drawable.pic48,
            R.drawable.pic49,
            R.drawable.pic50,
            R.drawable.pic51,
            R.drawable.pic52,
            R.drawable.pic53,
            R.drawable.pic54,
            R.drawable.pic55,
            R.drawable.pic56,
            R.drawable.pic57,
            R.drawable.pic58,
            R.drawable.pic59,
            R.drawable.pic60,
            R.drawable.pic61,
            R.drawable.pic62,
            R.drawable.pic63,
            R.drawable.pic64,
            R.drawable.pic65,
            R.drawable.pic66

        };

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
          return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) 
        {
          return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) 
        {
          Context context = Fragment1.this;//<---------here are the error "Fragment1.this;"
          ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
          int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
              R.dimen.padding_medium);//<---------here are the error ".padding_medium"
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
          imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
          ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
          return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) 
        {
          ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
      }



}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.androidbegin.menuviewpagertutorial;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    // Declare Variables
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from drawer_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        // Get the Title
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // Generate title
        title = new String[] { "Title Fragment 1", "Title Fragment 2" };

        // Generate subtitle
        subtitle = new String[] { "Subtitle Fragment 1", "Subtitle Fragment 2" };

        // Generate icon
        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.action_about, R.drawable.action_settings };

        // Locate DrawerLayout in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        // Locate ListView in drawer_main.xml
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

        // Set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // Pass string arrays to MenuListAdapter
        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(MainActivity.this, title, subtitle,
                icon);

        // Set the MenuListAdapter to the ListView
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        // Capture listview menu item click
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // Enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Set the title on the action when drawer open
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // ListView click listener in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment1);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        // Get the title followed by the position
        setTitle(title[position]);
        // Close drawer
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            // If there are back-stack entries, leave the FragmentActivity
            // implementation take care of them.
            manager.popBackStack();

        } else {
            // Otherwise, ask user if he wants to leave :)
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**MenuListAdapter.java**

```
    package com.androidbegin.menuviewpagertutorial;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] mTitle;
    String[] mSubTitle;
    int[] mIcon;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MenuListAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] subtitle,
            int[] icon) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mSubTitle = subtitle;
        this.mIcon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitle.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mTitle[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Declare Variables
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtSubTitle;
        ImageView imgIcon;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent,
                false);

        // Locate the TextViews in drawer_list_item.xml
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        txtSubTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);

        // Locate the ImageView in drawer_list_item.xml
        imgIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        // Set the results into TextViews
        txtTitle.setText(mTitle[position]);
        txtSubTitle.setText(mSubTitle[position]);

        // Set the results into ImageView
        imgIcon.setImageResource(mIcon[position]);

        return itemView;
    }

}
```

**fragment1.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<Gallery

    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/switcher1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/Fragment1" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**tandaamaran.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**AndroidManiefest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidbegin.menuviewpagertutorial"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should init your ui-objects like this:

```
    @Override 
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        initUIobjects(view);
    }

    private void initUIobjects(View view){
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    //... and so on
    }
```

instead onCreate

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)

`setContentView` is a method of activity class. You can initialize views once the layout is inflated. So `ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager)` fails.

I am not sure what you are doing or from where you copy pasted the code.

You probably want activity context

```
  Context context = Fragment1.this;
```

So use `getActivtiy()`

```
  Context context = getActivity();
```