# How to get ids of widget without setcontent view?

Tags: android, layout, setcontentview

I am new in android.I have a simple doubt,Is there any way to get id of a widget from some layout without set it as content view ?? I am looking to invisible a view from a class .I used the code

```
 View  b = findViewById(R.id.id2);
 b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But error in "id",is it possible to get ids if widget from a java class without set as contentview ?? please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate the views separately and then use `findViewById` on the root of the inflated layout.

```
// inside of Activity, you can use 'this' for the context
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout);
// from your example
View b = root.findViewById(R.id.id2);
b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

At this point however these views are not part of your Activity's view hierarchy and will not be seen by the user. You will have to add them either by using `setContentView(root)` or by finding a `ViewGroup` in the current view hierarchy and calling `viewGroup.addView(root)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
Button filterButton = new Button(YourActivity.this);
filterButton.setVisibility(filterButton.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(view) with a layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

See below link :-

[Why findViewById() is returning null if setcontentview() is not called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476424/why-findviewbyid-is-returning-null-if-setcontentview-is-not-called)

'But error in "id",is it possible to get ids if widget from a java class without set as contentview ?? '

You have to create dynamic view then you do not have need to call setcontentview.

[how to set setContentView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252868/how-to-set-setcontentview)

[Is there a way to set setContentView(int id) dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248861/is-there-a-way-to-set-setcontentviewint-id-dynamically)